# Manually set the input field to invalid in an AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple directive, whose purpose is to do two things:

1. Make a "masked" input field, from a non-angular 3rd party library work with NgModel.
2. Check the input value, for a valid unix time stamp.

I'm using **Jasny bootstrap** plugin, to create the "data masking" for a date input.

#### My input field:

```
  <input ng-class="{ 'input_error' : bdayForm.bday.$invalid && !bdayForm.bday.$pristine 
    || bdayForm.bday.$invalid && submitted }" 
    apply-scope ng-model="bday"  name="bday" id="bday" type="text" placeholder="" 
    data-mask="99/99/9999" class="required">
```

Notice the `data-mask` attribute. This will apply the data masking functionality provided by the plugin. The `apply-scope` attribute is the name of directive I created. Here is the code I have so far:

```
app.directive("applyScope", function() {
  return {

    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      element.bind('keydown', (e) => {

        const arr = element[0].value.split("/")
        let newBday = `${arr[2]}/${arr[1]}/${arr[0]} 00:00:00`
        newBday = (new Date(newBday).getTime() / 1000 + 7200) //This will convert the bday to unix time stamp.

        if (!newBday) {
          return false;
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newBday);

      })
    }
  };
});
```

As you can see, I'm splitting the "99/99/9999" string into an array, and then I try to construct a unix time stamp.

If it's `NaN`, I return `false`. What I would like to achieve though, is setting the input field to `$invalid`, when the function returns `false`. I need to use this `$invalid` property, to make my `ng-class` conditioning work (basically just apply red color to the input)

Can someone explain me how it should be done?

Comment: `ngModel.$setValidity('date', isValid);`

Comment: I see, thank you. But how would you do it in a more "abstract" way? Meaning: let's say i don't know the name the user gave the field? I would need something like "this", when referring to an object. Is there a way to abstract it out?

Comment: Well it is the date that you validate, so in convention you set the validity of the 'date' property. Or you name it something like `ngModel.$setValidity('birthday', isValid);`